# Login as another user

Tags: administration, login

I have the 'login as another' user feature enabled.
Is there a way to restrict how long this admin can be logged in as another user?
Fir example I want him to be logged in as another user for only 3 hours as I want to troubleshoot something!

Any pointers appreciated.

Dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In production orgs, the 'login as' feature can be provided to the company's admin for a min of 1 day to a maximum of 1 year. However, the user can revoke the access to his record at any point. So it is possible to restrict access only for 3 hours but this is a manual step as the user has to go into his user settings and revoke access. Below is a screenshot for that.

[image]

Comment: ..assuming the login access policy doesn't allow the admin to bypass that.

Comment: Thanks but that is always assumed. Allowing it on production orgs will be a major breach of security.

Comment: Most orgs we've seen allow admins to bypass.

Comment: What happens if the admin is already logged in when permission is revoked?